# dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n$ over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: linear-algebra

What can i say about dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n$ over $\mathbb{C}$ ??

I know dimension of $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is 2 where basis is $\{1, i\}$ but what about $dim_{\mathbb{C}}{\mathbb{R}}$

Comment: When you say that $\mathbb{C}$ has dimension 2 over $\mathbb{R}$, what you are really saying is that the vector space $(\mathbb{C}, +, \cdot,\mathbb{R})$ has dimension two. You are asking for the dimension of something like $(\mathbb{R}, +', \cdot',\mathbb{C})$, so who are $+'$ and $\cdot'$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}^n$ is not a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space in itself. $i(1,0,0)\notin\mathbb{R}^3$, so it fails to be closed. But, if you have an even-dimensional vector space $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, you can manufacture an isomorphism (of real vector spaces) to $\mathbb{C}^n$. Can you construct it?

Comment: how i construct if i have even dimensional vector space $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ , elaborate plz..

Comment: You can identify $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$ as real vector spaces via $a+ bi \mapsto (a,b)$.  Hence you can identify $\mathbb{C}^n$ with $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ via $$(a_1 + b_1 i, ... , a_n + b_ni) = (a_1, b_1, ... , a_n, b_n)$$

Comment: so dimension of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ ober $\mathbb{C}$ is $n$.

Answer (score 3):

It makes no sense. If $V$ is a vector space over $\Bbb C$ then, $zv$ must belong to $V$ for every $z\in \Bbb C$ and $v\in V$, but for $x\in \Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$, $ix\notin \Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Or in other words,  $\Bbb R^n$ is not a $\Bbb C$-space.  So its dimension is not defined.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ can be a $\mathbb{C}$-space using appropriate definitions for the operations. I know this seems very pedantic but I think is important to point out that his question makes no sense until he defines properly the vector space he wants to study.